# Split hms column into 30 minute intervals

Tags: r, lubridate

I have participant data during an exercise test, which includes participant ID, the condition (either Environmental or Control) and the total time taken to complete the test. A small example of my data:

```
    RawData <- data.frame(
      ParticipantID = c (1:6), 
      Condition = c("Control","Experimental","Experimental","Control","Experimental","Control"),
      Time = c("04:34:22","02:48:47","04:22:06","02:57:11","02:07:11","05:34:22"))
```

I then used the `lubridate` package so I have time in `hms` via:

```
RawData <- RawData %>% 
  mutate(TotalTime = hms::as_hms(Time))
```

Now I wish to create a new column, that bins each `RawData$TotalTime` result into a category including: Sub2, Sub230, Sub3, Sub330, Sub4, Sub430, Sub5, Sub530 and Sub6. I could probably do this via a long `case_when` statement but is there an easy way to do this in `lubridate` given I am after 30 minute intervals?

My desired output would be:

```
   RawData <- data.frame(
      ParticipantID = c (1:6), 
      Condition = c("Control","Experimental","Experimental","Control","Experimental","Control"),
      Time = c("04:34:22","02:48:47","04:22:06","02:57:11","02:07:11","05:34:22"),
      Category = c("Sub5","Sub3","Sub430","Sub3","Sub230","Sub6"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ceiling_date` function with `units` as "30 mins".

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

RawData %>%
  mutate(TotalTime = as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%T'),
         Category = format(ceiling_date(TotalTime, '30 mins'), "%H%M")) %>%
  select(-TotalTime)


#  ParticipantID    Condition     Time Category
#1             1      Control 04:34:22     0500
#2             2 Experimental 02:48:47     0300
#3             3 Experimental 04:22:06     0430
#4             4      Control 02:57:11     0300
#5             5 Experimental 02:07:11     0230
#6             6      Control 05:34:22     0600
```

Comment: Is there a way to also combine the term "Sub" at the front of the category? I am guessing `sprintf` might be helpful but I'm unsure where to start!

Comment: `Category = paste0('Sub', format(ceiling_date(TotalTime, '30 mins'), "%H%M")))`